# does Akka manage Camel consumer thread or Camel context manage consumer thread?

Tags: multithreading, akka, pool, consumer

the camel document mentioned that CamelContext manages threads for its consumers.
Akka integrated Camel thru Camel extension. we know that Akka has its own thread pools (dispatcher). so the question is: who manages Akka Camel consumer/actor threads? if CamelContext manages threads, then how can I configure the thread pools in cfg files or code?

Answer (score 0):

So there are several threads at work here. Camel manages the ExecutorService for its Component threads while Akka Camel manages the ExecutorService for the Consumer Actors. It is not the Camel thread that runs the Akka Actor.

You configure the Akka Dispatchers in the Akka configuration and the Camel ExecutionServices in the Camel configuration.